# Visual Studio 2012 - recuperar arquivo excluído

Tags: visual-studio

Tem como recuperar algum arquivo excluído, como por exemplo uma classe ou página html no visual studio 2012?

Comment: Este projeto estava no TFS?

Comment: Não estava. Não era nada de importante, somente deletei um arquivo sem querer e pensei se teria como recuperá-lo.

Answer (score 2):

A única "solução" que encontrei foi esta: quando excluímos um arquivo, seja uma classe ou uma View, do Visual Studio 2012, eles vão para a lixeira. Portanto se você não limpou a lixeira, ainda há como recuperar esses arquivos.

Answer (score -2):

Acabei de excluir um arquivo que não precisava e o encontrei junto de outros excluídos na lixeira do computador. Fica tudo lá.